# Why is FXMLLoader giving me an error when I try to run?

Tags: java, javafx

Whenever I try to run this piece of code, I always get the error. I already have JavaFX configured properly.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")); // this line causes the error
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:465)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:901)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/jacobweiner10/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/cc968ee777ba3f29b08974baa534a944/redhat.java/jdt_ws/Pi%20program_e74fad27/bin/sample.fxml:9

        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:933)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:981)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:755)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3331)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3255)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3227)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3203)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3196)
        at Main.start(Main.java:11)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:847)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:484)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:457)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:456)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:316)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Controller
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:931)
        ... 22 more
Exception running application Main
```

Contents of "sample.fxml" file:

```xml
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
          gridLinesVisible="true">
    <!--<columnConstraints>--> 
        <!--<ColumnConstraints percentWidth="50.0"/>-->
        <!--<ColumnConstraints percentWidth="50.0"/>-->
    <!--</columnConstraints>-->

    <Button text="Button One" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
    <Button text="Button Two" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="Button Three" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
    <Button text="Really Long Button Four more text more text more text more text more text more text " GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
    <Button text="Button Five" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="0"/>
</GridPane>
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: The class `sample.Controller` does not exist.

Comment: This line of the stack trace tells you what the problem is: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sample.Controller`

Comment: make sure the class name for the controller is correct - mis-spelling it in the fxml or being at a location somewhere else in your source tree might produce the error